# D3.js Grouped Bar chart using nested file

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have a problem with my JavaScript code for D3.js. I am trying to use the `d3.nest()` function to summarize my large CSV file and then create visualizations from it. I am trying to make a grouped bar chart as shown here : [mbostock's example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051).

But nothing is displayed on the page when I load it up. The grouped chart is meant to show the number of actual and predicted repairs values based on the modules (`module_category`, as shown in the sample data below):

```
module_category,component_category,date_repair,actual,predicted,
M1,P06,1/1/2009,39,63,
M1,P06,2009/10,3,4,2009/10/1
M1,P06,2009/11,4,3,2009/11/1
M1,P06,2009/12,4,2,2009/12/1
M1,P06,2009/02,29,45,2009/02/1
M1,P06,2009/03,29,32,2009/03/1
M1,P06,2009/04,10,22,2009/04/1
M1,P06,2009/05,13,15,2009/05/1
M1,P06,2009/06,9,16,2009/06/1
M1,P06,2009/07,7,12,2009/07/1
```

This is the code I've written so far:

```js
(function() { 
  
  var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 60},
      width = 980 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

  var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

  var color = d3.scale.category10();

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x0)
      .orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

  var svg = d3.select("#maincontent").append("svg")
      .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
      .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var tip=d3.tip()
              .attr("class","d3-tip")
              .offset([-10, 0])
              .html(function(d) { return "No. of repairs: " + d.value; });

  d3.csv("data/Consolidated_result.csv", function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    data = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.module_category;})
      .rollup(function(values){
          var counts = {}, keys = ['actual', 'predicted']
          keys.forEach(function(key){
              counts[key] = d3.sum(values, function(d){ return d[key]})
          })
          return counts
      })
      .entries(data);

      console.log(data);

    x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.key; }));
    x1.domain(d3.keys(data)).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.values, function(d) { return d.values.length; }); })]);

    svg.call(tip);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
        .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Number of Repairs");

    var module = svg.selectAll(".module")
        .data(data, function(d){ return d.values; })
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "g")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.key) + ",0)"; });

    module.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.values); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.values); })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.key); });

    var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
        .data(d3.keys(data).slice().reverse())
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

    legend.append("rect")
        .attr("x", width - 18)
        .attr("width", 18)
        .attr("height", 18)
        .style("fill", color);

    legend.append("text")
        .attr("x", width - 24)
        .attr("y", 9)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(function(d) { return d; });


  });
}
```

I am also trying to add interactivity to the chart to allow the user to view the components related to a module when they click on it. The picture below is the ideal chart I am looking to make:

[image: groupedBarChart sample picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues in your code:

**Issue1**: CSV is incorrect actual and predicted data have dates in them:

```
module_category,component_category,date_repair,actual,predicted,
M1,P06,1/1/2009,39,63,
M1,P06,2009/10,3,4,2009/10/1
M1,P06,2009/11,4,3,2009/11/1
M1,P06,2009/12,4,2,2009/12/1
```

should have been:

```
module_category,component_category,date_repair,actual,predicted
M1,P06,1/1/2009,39,63
M2,P06,2009/10/1,3,4
M3,P06,2009/10/1,30,40
```

**Issue2**: domain for x1 is wrong.
Your code:

```
x1.domain(d3.keys(data)).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
```

here `d3.keys(data)` is undefined

should have been

```
x1.domain(['actual', 'predicted']).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
```

**Issue3**: domain for y is wrong.
Your code:

```
 y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.values, function(d) { return d.values.length; }); })]);
```

should have been

```
//store all the values in array
var yval = [];
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      yval.push(d.values.actual);
      yval.push(d.values.predicted);
    });
 //then do max on that
y.domain([0, d3.max(yval)]);
```

**Issue4**: data set is incorrect.

```
 module.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data) //you are passing an object but it should be an array
      .enter().append("rect")
```

should have been

```
module.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    var ary = [];
    ary.push({name:"actual", value:d.values.actual});
    ary.push({name:"predicted", value:d.values.predicted});
    return ary;
  })
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TzayEYkeddUsYRjtL2TV?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: If i wanted to add interactivity in a way that when a rect for a particular module is clicked e.g "M2"the chart updates to show all the components with the number of repair e.g "P2" "P4" "P6". Any hints as to how I can achieve that?